# Fedora 31/Gnome: I don't know how to launch X apps manually

Tags: fedora, gnome

I can start xterm with the dock and the "applications" button.

But inside the xterm, if I type for instance "xterm" again, I can't open.  Specifically, I get the error `xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: localhost:0.0`.  Setting DISPLAY to `:0.0`, `localhost:0.0`, or the IP address followed by `:0.0` doesn't work.

Fedora 31 on a Thinkpad T470p.

Comment: Exactly what happens when you try to start xterm like that?

Comment: added to write-up, thanks!

Comment: I have a feeling that something in your shell's startup scripts actually sets DISPLAY _when it shouldn't..._ (That is, GNOME receives the correct display address, starts Xterm, but then bash/zsh inside that Xterm overwrites it with a different one.) Can you take a look at `systemctl --user show-environment` to find DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY there, as well as `ls -l /tmp/.X11-unix/` to see what sockets exist in there? Additionally, what does `cat /proc/$PPID/environ | tr \\0 \\n | egrep "^DISPLAY|^XAUTH"` output inside the working xterm?

Comment: Are you running under Wayland by any chance?

Comment: OK, apparently I am... I guess?  There's an XWayland process running for instance.  Reading the Wiki page I'm not sure what that means I need to do though?  Even if my xterm process is no longer talking X protocol to an Xserver, but instead talking Wayland protocol to a Wayland server, how do I launch xterm, xeyes etc. from inside an xterm?

Comment: I don't actually understand this well enough to even know what keywords to google...

Comment: It *is* talking X, that's why there's Xwayland in the middle (it's an X server that translates everything to Wayland). Doesn't really change things much, though – xterm connecting to Xwayland is supposed to work exactly like xterm connecting to Xorg or any other X11 server. The questions I had are still relevant.

Comment: Thanks and will do so, cannot reboot that computer to Linux until this weekend.